# Prove that there exists $S \in L(V /U, W)$ such that $T = S \circ \pi$ if and only if $U \subset \ker(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Not sure on how to approach the following problem:
Suppose $T \in L(V, W)$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ . Let $\pi$ be the quotient map from $V$ onto $V/U$. Prove that there exists $S \in L(V /U, W)$ such that $T = S \circ \pi$ if and only if $U \subset \ker(T)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$T=S\pi\implies\;\forall\,u\in U\;,\;\;Tu=S\pi u=S(u+U)=S\overline0=0\implies U\subset\ker T$$

with $\;\overline 0=\;$ the zero element in the quotient space $\;V/U\;$ .

On the other direction: if $\;U\subset\ker T\;$, define

$$S: V/U\to W\;,\;\;S(v+U):=Tv$$

Observe this is well defined since

$$v+U=v'+U\iff v-v'\in U\subset\ker T\implies 0=T(v-v')=Tv-Tv'\implies$$

$$Tv=Tv'\implies S(v+U)=S(v'+U)$$

and it is easy to check $\;S\;$ indeed is a linear map, and now

$$\forall\,v\in V\;,\;\;S\pi v=S(v+U):=Tv\implies S\pi=T$$

and we've finished.

Answer (score 1):

We first define a map S : V /U → W: for any ~v + U ∈ V /U, 
define S(~v + U) = T(~v). 
This is a well defined map, since if ~v+U and ~w+U give the same element in V/U, then by
”⇒”: If U + ~v = U + ~v0, then ~v = 0 + ~v ∈ U + ~v = U + ~v0. 
So there exists ~u ∈ U such that
~v = ~u + ~v0, or ~v − ~v0 = ~u ∈ U.
"⇐": If ~v − ~v0 ∈ U, then for any ~w = ~u + ~v ∈ U + ~v, ~w = ~u + (~v0 − ~v) + ~v0 ∈ U + ~v0. So U + ~v ⊂ U + ~v0.
Similarly we have U + ~v0 ⊂ U + ~v. 
This concludes U + ~v = U + ~v0.
Which shows that we have ~v− ~w ∈ U = ker(T).
As a result T(~v) = T( ~w) + T(~v − ~w) = T( ~w). 
So the image of ~v + U and ~w + U of S is the same. 
Also S is a linear map. 
For we see that
S((~v + U) + ( ~w + U)) 
= S(~v + ~w + U) 
= T(~v + ~w) 
= T(~v) + T( ~w) 
= S(~v + U) + S( ~w + U),S(a(vv + U)) 
= S((a~v) + U) 
= T(a~v) 
= aT(~v) 
= aS(~v + U).
These give additivity and homogeneity of S. 
Finally S satisfies T = S ◦ π, because for any ~v ∈ V , we have
S(π(~v)) = S(~v + U) = T(~v).
And such a map is unique. 
Indeed, if S1 and S2 are two valid linear maps, for each ~v + U ∈ V /U, by
assumption that 
T = S1 ◦ π and T = S2 ◦ π,
S1(~v + U) = S1(π(~v)) = T(~v) = S2(π(~v)) = S2(~v + U).